# How to increase the speed of find_elements_by_xpath

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am working on a selenium project. In the project I am opening multiple walmart pages and checking if there is a `nav` inside a div. If the `nav` exists do something else continue to the next page.

[image]

Right now The program is able to locate the nav if the nav exists in the page. but if the nav does not exist, it program takes too long to continue along with the code.

Is there anyway to increase the speed with which the program searches the code.

this is my code

```
nav_button_path = "//div[@class='modal modal--active-fill responsive-modal prod-fulfillmentOptionsModal prod-AccessFulfillmentModal prod-AccessSlidePanel']//nav[@class='persistent-subnav']"
nav_button = driver.find_elements_by_xpath(nav_button_path)

if not nav_button:
    ...

else:
    ...
```

in the above code the `else condition` runs if the nav is found. This runs quickly. But the `if condition` takes a long time to run as the program takes a long time to search for the nav in the webpage if the nav does not exist.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you can try to update the xpath value to be more performant - if you post you HTML code we might try to help you.

Comment: @AlinStelian [walmart link](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Frito-Lay-Family-Fun-Mix-Snacks-Variety-Pack-18-Count/971503257?wpa_bd=&wpa_pg_seller_id=F55CDC31AB754BB68FE0B39041159D63&wpa_ref_id=wpaqs:SzCYddybOcj-0PfWPsMsiEaXtUK5Q7dDbJKnaQQe_BKldL6qCzRD1sHN5Oq9FyQlgQSJ6odAn4kKNkJmVifRIJARVsLFpKXdYezVJvk7DsY4FK8VuFrjd1XYVCZnw36fS3KJ99kuOoWiPmv0bPOmqfEE1ctJlZje84kKgwi59EWeyCxKnoN4VKJ0hw5djDQMzvutgEcxFvKSYet36H1sSQ&wpa_tag=__tag__&wpa_aux_info=__aux_info__&wpa_pos=1&wpa_plmt=__plmt__&wpa_aduid=__aduid__). Please click the `More delivery & pickup options` and the check the developer console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the reason of delay is implicit wait that you use. It should fix your problem:

```
driver.implicitly_wait(0)
```

Comment: Should I add this after `find_elements_by_xpath`? And can you please explain how this will work?

Comment: I tried this. But this does not seem to reduce the time

Comment: @Sashaank you need to set it up after creating driver. Default value is 0 so it could affect your tests only if you set up some value. I suggested that you did it.

Comment: @Sashaank try to simplify locator, for example: `.modal-content .persistent-subnav`

Comment: I tried what you said. The problem was I had initially added `driver.implicitly_wait(10)` somewhere else in the code. This works now. Thanks a lot